# Isolating matrix of numbers in a picture with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I've been trying to segment a picture of a matrix into its individual cells so I can then perform OCR on them, but have been running into a lot of trouble. A sample picture would be something like this:

[image]

I've been trying a combination of Canny edge detection, Gaussian blurring, and contours -- but haven't had much luck. Most tutorials I've seen assume a box around the item of interest, whereas with a matrix it's usually a partial box.

Once I can crop the matrix I believe performing similar steps [this tutorial here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) will be sufficient.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm to help crop out the matrix and then it's individual cells?

So far my code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pickle
import imutils

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread('matrix.jpeg')
    image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)
    # cv2.imwrite('test.jpeg', edged)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it going to be a 3x3 matrix always?

Comment: No I was not planning on that.

Comment: Maybe a line detector may help you, find the 2 longest lines that are parallel to each other. With this two lines define you can create a box to isolate the numbers inside

Comment: I actually will know how big the matrix will be, just not always 3x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the shape of the brackets are unique, you can use them to isolate the RHS of the equation. One way to do this would be to use `cv2.matchShapes()`using the following image.

[image: bracket_image]

The advantage of using `cv2.matchShapes()` is that it is translation,rotation and scale invariant. This means that using the same image of the bracket, we can detect both brackets (one is 180 degrees rotated) at any scale. Now that we have found the contours representing the brackets, we simply trim the image to the minimum and maximum x-coordinates, resulting in the following image
[image]

The same can be achieved with the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('bracket.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('test.png',0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img1, 127, 255,0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img2, 127, 255,0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt1 = contours[0]
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2,2,1)

match_values = []

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cnt2 = contours[i]
    ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1,cnt2,1,0.0)
    match_values.append(ret)

    # Un-comment the next set of lines if you would like to see the match rate of each contour
    # print(ret)
    # img = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    # cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i, (255,255,0), 3)
    # cv2.imshow('contour', img)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

best_matches = np.argsort(match_values)[-3:][::-1]
limits = np.vstack(( contours[best_matches[0]].reshape(-1,2), contours[best_matches[1]].reshape(-1,2))).reshape(-1,2)

cropped_img = img2[:, np.min(limits[:,0]):np.max(limits[:,0]) ]
cv2.imwrite('cropped_img.png', cropped_img)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much. Given this cropped pic, would you recommend that I crop out the side bars before trying to isolate each individual digit?

Comment: Yes I would recommend that. Though an easy alternative would be to simply remove the two contours with the largest areas (assuming you use contours)